# How to reduce the cost?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, query-optimization

```
select * from XXCNN_AR_FIN016_MONTH_END
where period_name like '%-15'
```

I tried to create index on column period name but cost will not reduce .

Cost of this query is 12702.

After creating index, explain plan is showing options as storage full. For this I want to ask you the question: after creating index, why its not showing index scan or other scan?

How do I reduce the cost and time for this?

Answer (score 2):

If leading characters are specified in the LIKE pattern, index can be used (for patterns like this '51-%').

The solution is to create functional index using REVERSE function

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_XXCNN_AR_FIN016_MONTH_END_reverse ON XXCNN_AR_FIN016_MONTH_END(REVERSE(period_name ));
```

And then query like this:

```
select * from XXCNN_AR_FIN016_MONTH_END
where REVERSE(period_namex) like REVERSE('%-15');
```

Oracle will recognize REVERSE() function in the query predicate and will use index.

Comment: "... using REVERSE function" >> that's pretty much a *bad idea*. You shouldn't use and certainly not suggest someone else to use undocumented functions. At least, it was undocumented when I last checked ...

Comment: its working and now cost will reduce as 9526.

Answer (score 1):

Too few data to answer, I'm afraid.

Though, you didn't say what kind of an index you created. Did you try a function-based index?

```
CREATE INDEX i1_xx
   ON xxcnn_ar_fin016_month_end (SUBSTR (period_name, -2));
```

and rewrite query to

```
SELECT *
  FROM xxcnn_ar_fin016_month_end
 WHERE SUBSTR (period_name, -2) = '15';
```

Comment: at the time of creating index its showing me error like this ORA-01702: a view is not appropriate here.

Comment: Looks like xxcnn_ar_fin016_month_end  is a VIEW, not a table. So yes, you can't create index on a view - but you should be able to do it on an underlying table's column. I suggest you try it.